# why the select query through python throwing syntax error?

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I am trying to connect to a Postgres DB and execute a simple select query. But I am getting errors. Below is the sample program

```
import psycopg2 as ps

param_dic = ps.connect(
    host="localhost",
    database="Test_DB",
    user="username",
    password="password"
)

cur = param_dic.cursor()
cur.execute("select * from  <schema_name>.'employee_tbl'") # I am 
rows = cur.fetchall()

for r in rows:
    print(r)
```

I get below error:

```
psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "'tbl_name'"
LINE 1: select * from  <schema_name>.'tbl_name'
```

If I use

```
cur.execute("select * from <schema_name>.'Employee_TBL'")
```

Still, I get the same error.

Note: when I check my pgAdmin, I see below as the table name

```
<schema_name>.Employee_TBL
```

So, what is the right way to execute SQL queries on a Postgres table?

Comment: I think `<schema_name>` should be replaced with real table/schema name. Or you replaced here real name with it to hide secure info? If your table name is Employee_TBL then just do `select * from Employee_TBL;`

Answer (score 1):

replace <schema_name>.'Employee_TBL'" with true value :
dbo.Employee_TBL or another schema name in your database

Comment: I hid the schema for the security purpose. If I just put table_name without the schema name, I get the same error.  cur.execute("select * from 'Employee_TBL'"). I tried with and without a single quote.

Comment: When I only add the tabel name, I get "psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "employee_tbl" does not exist
LINE 1: select * from  Employee_TBL"

Comment: So what’s your schema name if it’s not public?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's just a typo, use double quotes for the table if you need to.
**Single quotes indicate a string literal.**

```
import psycopg2
conn = psycopg2.connect(...)
cur = conn.cursor()
    
cur.execute('SELECT * FROM public.servers')
print(len(cur.fetchall()))

cur.execute('SELECT * FROM PUBLIC."servers"')
print(len(cur.fetchall()))
```

Out:

```
6
6
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing quotes around ‘emloyee_tbl’

Answer (score 0):

The overriding issue is that you created a table name with quoted mixed case. This means that from then on you need to quote the name to be able to use it:

```
create table "Mixed_Case" (id int, fld_1 varchar);
select * from mixed_case;
ERROR:  relation "mixed_case" does not exist
LINE 1: select * from mixed_case;

select * from "Mixed_Case";
 id | fld_1 
----+-------
(0 rows)

--NOTE the double quotes.
```

For more information see [4.1.1. Identifiers and Key Words](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS)

For the psycopg2 case:

```
import psycopg2
con = psycopg2.connect("dbname='test' host='localhost' user='aklaver'")
cur = con.cursor()
# Single quoted
cur.execute("select * from public.'Mixed_Case'")
SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "'Mixed_Case'"
LINE 1: select * from public.'Mixed_Case'
# Identifiers need double quotes

# Changing to double quotes
cur.execute('select * from public."Mixed_Case"')
# No error.
# You can also use Postgres functions
cur.execute("select * from quote_ident('public.Mixed_Case')")
```

For more on Postgres functions and methods see [string functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html)

Also in psycopg2 there is the [sql](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html) module that allows you to work with identifiers:

```
from psycopg2 import sql
sql_str = sql.SQL("select * from public.{}").format(sql.Identifier('Mixed_Case'))
print(sql_str.as_string(con))                                                                                                                                             
select * from public."Mixed_Case"
cur.execute(sql_str)
```